# Excel : VBA procedure to compare two columns and highligh the different cells and change the value of the identical cells

Tags: excel, vba

VBA procedure to compare two different columns in two different worksheets and highlight the different cells in this column and change the equal cells value to a new sequential number - the data doesn't have to be sorted before using the macro

Comment: Hi, Is the below an answer or your attempt so far which should be an [edit] to the question? And please format it legibly. Select all the code and insert it within code tags (Ctrl + K) . It's also very difficult to relate the above to the below without any sample data and related logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
' data are in column b and column d in sheet 1 and sheet2 respectively.
' data doesn't have to be sorted 
' the student ids which are not available in both columns, will be highlighted and have a cell's color background. 
'Get the last row
    Dim Report As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

Set Report = Excel.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'You could also use Excel.ActiveSheet _
                                      if you always want this to run on the current sheet.
 Set Report2 = Excel.Worksheets("Sheet2")
 'lastRow = Report.UsedRange.Rows.Count

lastRow = 29

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim seqNo As Integer, seqNo2 As Integer
seqNo = 0
seqNo2 = 0

For i = 2 To lastRow
    For j = 2 To lastRow
        If Report.Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then 'This will omit blank cells at the end (in the event that the column lengths are not equal.
            If InStr(1, Report2.Cells(j, 4).Value, Report.Cells(i, 2).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                'You may notice in the above instr statement, I have used vbTextCompare instead of its numerical value, _
                I find this much more reliable.

                Report.Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White background
                Report.Cells(i, 2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color

                Exit For
            Else
                Report.Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) 'Dark red background
                Report.Cells(i, 2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 'Light red font color
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'Now I use the same code for the second column, and just switch the column numbers.
For i = 2 To lastRow
    For j = 2 To lastRow
        If Report2.Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, Report.Cells(j, 2).Value, Report2.Cells(i, 4).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Report2.Cells(i, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White background
                Report2.Cells(i, 4).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color
                seqNo2 = seqNo2 + 1
                Report2.Cells(i, 4).Value = seqNo2
                Report.Cells(j, 2) = seqNo2
                Exit For
            Else
                Report2.Cells(i, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) 'Dark red background
                Report2.Cells(i, 4).Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 'Light red font color
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What about a number not used but within the original series?

Answer (score 0):

this code will highlight values not in both lists:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim report1 As Worksheet, report2 As Worksheet
    Set report1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set report2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim ids1 As Variant, ids2 As Variant
    With report1
        ids1 = Application.Transpose(.Range("B2", .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value)
    End With
    With report2
        ids2 = Application.Transpose(.Range("D2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Value)
    End With

    ProcessOneReport report1, 2, ids2
    ProcessOneReport report2, 4, ids1
End Sub

Sub ProcessOneReport(report As Worksheet, icol As Long, ids As Variant)
    Dim validIdsRng As Range

    With report
        With .Range(.Cells(1, icol), .Cells(.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ids, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) < .Count Then
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
                    Set validIdsRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    .AutoFilter
                    validIdsRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    With .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible)
                        .Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) 'Dark red background
                        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 'Light red font color
                    End With
                    validIdsRng.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End With
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

a better answer to compare two columns (column A and A )in two different worksheets (sheet1 and sheet2) and highlight similar cells with same fill green colour.

Sub Demo()

```
Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, seqNo As Long

 Set ws1 = Excel.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set ws2 = Excel.Worksheets("Sheet2")
lastRow1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).Row
lastRow2 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).Row
```

' lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   ' lastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'   Set compareRange = ws1.Range("A1:A" & lastRow1)
   ' Set toCompare = ws2.Range("A1:A" & lastRow2)

```
seqNo = 0
For i = 1 To lastRow2
    For j = 1 To lastRow1
        If ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            If ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                seqNo = seqNo + 1
                ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value = seqNo
                ws1.Cells(j, 1).Value = seqNo
                ws2.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                ws1.Cells(j, 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                Exit For
            Else
                'ws2.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbWhite
                'ws1.Cells(j, 1).Interior.Color = vbWhite
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

End Sub